# Printing grid values from lists in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

In this exercise I am doing I have a list

```
grid = [['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
       ['.', 'O', 'O', '.', '.', '.'],
       ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.', '.'],
       ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.'],
       ['.', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'],
       ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.'],
       ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.', '.'],
       ['.', 'O', 'O', '.', '.', '.'],
       ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']]
```

I have to write a small program that cycles through the list and prints as follows grid[1][0], grid[2][0], grid[3][0] etc to show this picture

```
..OO.OO..
.OOOOOOO.
.OOOOOOO.
..OOOOO..
...OOO...
....O....
```

I have to do this using a loop within a loop, and I don't no whether it's just because I haven't had enough coffee this morning but I can't figure out how to do this. The code I have written just prints out the grid as it is, and the picture is on it's side

```
def printer(grid_list):

line = ""
for i in range(len(grid_list)):
    for char in range(len(grid_list[i])):
         line += grid_list[i][char]
    print(line)
    line = ""
```

Results:

```
......
.OO...
OOOO..
OOOOO.
.OOOOO
OOOOO.
OOOO..
.OO...
......
```

I know my problem is my code is cycling through and printing grid[0][1], grid[0][2], grid[0][3]. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated, it's quite a simple problem and I feel silly having to ask for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must add to line only first char from each inner array, then second etc.

```
for char in range(len(grid_list[0])):
    line = ""
    for i in range(len(grid_list)):
         line += grid_list[i][char]
    print(line)
```

This solution needs that all arrays inside must have same length.

Comment: your `line = ""` should be right after the first for loop, otherwise `line` is not defined

Answer (score 0):

You could take a little more advantage of Python by doing it this way, that's also more understandable in my opinion—which could be helpful early in the morning:

```
grid_list = [['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
             ['.', 'O', 'O', '.', '.', '.'],
             ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.', '.'],
             ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.'],
             ['.', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'],
             ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.'],
             ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.', '.'],
             ['.', 'O', 'O', '.', '.', '.'],
             ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']]

for i in range(len(grid_list[0])):
    print(''.join(row[i] for row in grid_list))
```